# Split a string value from JSON field and assign to YAML map

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, yaml

I want to split a string into various parts and assign it to fields in a YAML file. This is my JSON file.

```
{
 "App Name": "blah", 
 "Email": "blah@blah.com", 
 "Employee ID": "xyz", 
 "Load Balancing Method": "Round Robin", 
 "Network": "CMN", 
 "Pool Member": "pucq-spn-198 5001/tcp\r\npucq-spn-199 5002/tcp\r\npucq-spn-200 
  5003/tcp", 
 "Pool Monitor": "tcp", 
 "Pool name": "pool", 
 "SSL": "Required", 
 "VIP Name": "vs-ng"
}
```

This is the user submitted input from a web form, i am accessing this through the API. I want to split the values from `Pool Member` field to separate strings like `pucq-spn-198` `5001` `pucq-spn-199` `5002` and assign these to different fields in the YAML file. This is my YAML file.

```
nodes:
- description: PU
  host: 10.10.10.10
  monitors:
  - /Common/icmp
  name: node
- description: PU
  host: 10.10.10.10
  monitors:
  - /Common/icmp
  name: node-puex
partition: Common
pool:
  descriptions: PUE
  lb_method: Round Robin
  monitors:
  - /Common/tcp
  name: pool
pool_members:
- node_name: **pucq-spn-198**
  port: **5001**
- node_name: **pucq-spn-199**
  port: **5002**
server: gmly-p-01.blah.com
virtual_server:
  destination: 1.1.1.1
  ip_protocol: udp
  name: vs-ng
  pool: pool-pu-ind
  port: 999
  profiles:
  - name: fastL4
  type: performance-l4
```

I want to put the values in `-node_name:` and `port` under `pool_members:`. So far i tried something like this. But it does not work.

```
import json
import requests
import yaml

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/vip7.json"
r = requests.get(url)
json_file = json.loads(r.content)
j = json_file

with open('C:/pytest/vs-test.yml', 'r') as f:
    y = yaml.load(f)

# Assign JSON values to YAML

y['pool']['lb_method'] = j['Load Balancing Method']
y['pool']['name'] = j['Pool name']
y['virtual_server']['name'] = j['VIP Name']

y['pool_members']['node_name'] = j[0]['Pool Member']
print (y['pool_members']['node_name'])
```

Does nothing.

Also tried with split. It prints out the part `pucq-spn-198`.

```
pool = j['Pool Member']
p = pool.split()
y['pool_members']['node_name'] = pool[0:12]
print (pool[0:12])
```

but when i assign it like this `y['pool_members']['node_name'] = pool[0:12]` it does not work.

Comment: Your API seems to be on the localhost, so you control the JSON shape... Why not make nested objects in the JSON instead of a flat string?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, i thought about that, but even then i will have to split it and get `pucq-spn-198` and `5001` separately.

Comment: Aren't you trying to do that anyway? My point is have the server do, if possible

Comment: @cricket_007 This is the code i am using to create the JSON `if form.validate_on_submit():`  `with open(new_path,'w') as j:` `json.dump(data, j)` I'm very new to Python and if you can help me to create nested objects and put `pucq-spn-198` and `5001` as separate objects then that would be great :)

Comment: If you print the string, are `\r\n` still in it? If so, you'll need more than split

Comment: I would need to see what data is in the form, but the easy solution would not be to use a plaintext area and rather real list of input fields for names and ports

Comment: If i print the `pool member` it prints it out  line by line. \r\n are not printed. So we're good there. Unfortunately, they do not want to be edit the WebForm :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact problem that you're tying to highlight, but

1. `y['pool_members'] = pool_members` should have resulted in *something*.
2. I don't think `[0:12]` is correct when you want only **3** elements in the output, and there are *only **6*** elements after splitting the given members string value.

If you want to iterate over the pairs of the values, one way would be to make a generator function.

A full example of what you should be doing is seen here:

```
import json
import yaml 
from pprint import pprint

# defining the input data 
data = {
 "App Name": "blah", 
 "Email": "blah@blah.com", 
 "Employee ID": "xyz", 
 "Load Balancing Method": "Round Robin", 
 "Network": "CMN", 
 "Pool Member": "pucq-spn-198 5001/tcp\r\npucq-spn-199 5002/tcp\r\npucq-spn-200 5003/tcp", 
 "Pool Monitor": "tcp", 
 "Pool name": "pool", 
 "SSL": "Required", 
 "VIP Name": "vs-ng"
}

# Parse the input data and make sure there are even names and ports after a split
pool_members = data['Pool Member'].split()
amt = len(pool_members)
if amt % 2 != 0:
  raise Exception("Not all pool members have a name and port!")
# create a lazy iterator over the list
gen = (pm for pm in pool_members)
# Creates a list of key-value pairs 
pool_members = [{"node_name": next(gen), "port" : next(gen)} for _ in range(amt // 2)]

# Generating the YAML
'''
loading a yaml file just makes a dict, so pretend there 
was previously any pool members before, or an empty list
'''
yaml_data = {"pool_members": []}
print(3 * "-")
yaml_data["pool_members"] = pool_members
# TODO: Write YAML to file instead of console
print(yaml.dump(yaml_data, default_flow_style=False))
```

This outputs the following:

```
---
pool_members:
- node_name: pucq-spn-198
  port: 5001/tcp
- node_name: pucq-spn-199
  port: 5002/tcp
- node_name: pucq-spn-200
  port: 5003/tcp
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Just one more question, i'll be on my way. Say i have **4 lines** in pool members instead of **3 lines** in the JSON file, how can i create an additional line in the YAML of  `node_name` and `port` ? Because here we are explicitly mapping only 3 lines, but what if there are more? Can you suggest a modification in your above code to make it dynamic? :)

Comment: I never explicitly defined any size restrictions... The  `(3 * "-")` has nothing to do with the number of lines, it's a YAML thing to start with three dashes for a file... Only input validation was that the length is even. If there's another name and port in the data, it'll be part of the generator, therefore part of the output.